# javascript scroll help - title goes behind header

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

In the below javascript code am using for the page to scroll. On click of an arrow, it scrolls.

But the issue here is, i have a fixed header, and for the body contents below header i have given margin-top:150px;. When the page scrolls, the (Heading) titles (h1's on the page) are going behind the above header, were in the (Heading) title should be below header, is there anything to be done with the javascript here?

html:

```
<a class="anchorClick" href="#slide1"><div class="arrow-down-light-blue"></div></a>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".anchorClick").click(function(){
      $('html, body').animate({
       scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top // UPDATED LINE
      }, 1000);
   });
});
```

UPDATED WITH JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/zrdvv7co/3/

Comment: Could you put this in a working jsfiddle so we can see what you actually mean?

Comment: Fiddles using jQuery work better if you actually _embed_ jQuery … And your problem can simly be solved by subtracting 150 from the value that you let your script scroll to.

Comment: @CBroe:the 150px if i remove, the body pushes up behind the header, right there is the 1st title on the page.